# try catch block to display Error message

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax

I have a doubt about `Try` `Catch` blocks.
If I get an error in `Try` block then it will redirect to `Catch` block as per to the rule. So can I set visible = true to  my label into **catch block**.

i.e `lblError.visible=true;`

Is it correct as per coding standards? I am new to developing.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the visibility of your input elements to false in the catch block and display an error panel, for example, instead.

Answer (score 0):

That's right , whats wrong in that? Maybe you are not comfortable of visibling and setting lblError in catch block as try..catch can be appeared many places in your code, if it is, you can wrap up those two lines in a function and call it from every catch block.

You can also throw exception from catch block and handle them all at one place at session level or application level and redirect to one default error page where you can get the last error occurred and show user friendly message as per it.

You can also enable CustomErrors section in web.config and redirect to one specific page on any error occurred in the session.

```
try
{
  //statements;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  ShowError(ex);
}

void ShowError(Exception ex)
{
   //Log or Email error first
   LogOrEmailError(ex);

   // you can write user friendly message based on the exception provided or a generic error message.
   lblError.Visible = true;
   lblError.Text = GetUserFriendlyErrorMessage(ex); // or throw; if you are planing to handle error in global.ascx or through CustomErrors in web.config
}
```

Comment: You most likely do not want to show the actual error message to the user. It will most likely be way over their heads. Creating your own friendly version would be preferred.

Comment: @Josh True, One may not try to show the Error Message to the Users!

Comment: -1: very bad idea. You will never know what exceptions occurred. Your code will be broken, and you won't know it.

Comment: @JohnSaunders look at the answer again.

Comment: How about no try/catch block at all, and handle errors centrally, or through ASP.NET Health Monitoring? Otherwise, you'll have hundreds of try/catch blocks in your code.

Comment: What if you expect specific exception at only one place and had specific replacement message for that place in all the program only?

Answer (score 0):

Yes very much. You can write normal coding lines in catch block.

Comment: yep,thats i want to hear...actually im confused to write code in catch or not.

Comment: @FrankJames: Infact we use this technique (of writing in catch blocks) to have call a logger method/function which inserts some value in a database when ever an exception throws. This way we can keep track of errors and exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Catch block gives developer to recover the damage done by the error thrown in try block.

So You can write down any code that should run if an error appear in try block. i.e. Error logging

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can write any code inside a catch block, even `return` from method. The one moment is you must use `finaly{}` block to release any resource that you use in the method where exception was throwed, (for example, you use database connection).